# ccGL functions doesn't work with arm64 architecture

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, draw

Like you know, iTunes allows to upload only application with arm64 architecture since start of February. This new rule created some big problem for me.

I've created the app which has algorithm of building Terrain, which i found from "RayWenderlich" tutorials. It was working absolutely fine till i changed architecture.

Here's the method of drawing terrain:

```
-(void) draw{
CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
    ccGLBindTexture2D(justTexture.name);
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _highVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _highTexCoords);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHighVertices);
}
```

This method fill my terrain with texture:

```
ccGLBindTexture2D(justTexture.name);
```

And it absolutely doesn't work with arm64 architecture. Any thoughts?

P.S.: I tried to install cocos2d 2.2 which supports 64-bit architecture, but i have a lot of problems with it, so i just wondering can i fix it without replacing cocos2d engine.

I appreciate any help from you, guys.

EDIT 1: I found that texture fill area on iOs 7.0, but if device has iOs 8.0 and higher, it doesn't. Help me to figure it out, please(

Comment: Have you solved your issue yet? Looks like I have the same problem here.

Comment: I just had the same issue today as I was trying to get my game run at 64bit. Although I can not see how you construct your texture or position vertices, I assume that your problem caused by the size increase of CGFloat when you running on 64bit.


If you are using CGPoint to store x and y values, you should be careful too! The x and y members of CGPoint struct  are also in CGFloat. Instead of CGPoint you can make your own struct with x and y members that are float and use this struct to construct your _nHillVertices and  _nHighVertices